# AWS network traffic blocks during overnight backup of 50GB table

Tags: networking, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We download a backup of our RDS mysql to an AWS instance and then upload to S3. There is a single 50GB table in a DB on the host getting backed up.

When this process starts, network traffic on our other AWS instances hangs (literally, network bound processes appear to block on writing to eg AWS-based RabbitMQ exchanges, or block on a single sql UPDATE to the same RDS DB). When the DB backup completes archiving itself to S3, the network bound processes simply resume without error.

Non-network apps experience no hanging. Most, but not all, of our AWS instances with processes that connect to that RDS instance exhibit this mass hanging behaviour.

Is there some obscure AWS bandwidth limit we are hitting?

Comment: Have you considered that it could be related to the load on RDS instead of the network bandwidth? Maybe your RDS instance is just fully occupied with doing the backup, which affects clients doing other requests negatively.

Comment: Are you by chance using a NAT instance (instead of a NAT Gateway)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's about the EC2, but your network speed and bandwidth depends on your EC2 type, read this paragraph by Andreas:

What is the maximum network throughput of your EC2 instance? The answer to this question is key to choosing the type of an instance or defining monitoring alerts on network throughput. Unfortunately, you will only find very vague information about the networking capabilities of EC2 instances within AWS’s service description and documentation. That is why I run a network performance benchmark for almost all EC2 instance types within the last few days. The results are compiled into the following cheat sheet.

```
INSTANCE TYPE   Baseline (Gbit/s)   Burst (Gbit/s)
c4.large               0.62 
c4.xlarge              1.24 
c4.2xlarge             2.48
```

Read the full
https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/